# Minimizing the degree of outgoing edges in a digraph, does this problem have a name?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

I have a problem which can be rephrased in this way.

Suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a *digraph* (directed graph) and for each $v \in V$ we denote with $\delta^+(v)$ the number of outgoing edges of the vertex $v$.

I'm looking for a way to *swap* the edges (so $(i,j) \in E$ would become $(j,i)$) so that $\max_{v,w \in V} |\delta^+(v) - \delta^+(w)|$ is minimized.

Does this problem have a name in literature?

Comment: Although different, this seems related to the following thread: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48571/is-this-edge-orientation-optimization-problem-np-hard

Answer (score 1):

The similar problem of finding an orientation to minimize the *maximum* outdegree is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56891/unidentified-combinatorial-problem). You can solve your range minimization problem via integer linear programming as follows. For each undirected edge $(i,j)$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether direction $i\to j$ is chosen ($1$) or direction $j\to i$ is chosen ($0$). Let decision variables $M$ and $m$ represent the maximum and minimum outdegrees, respectively. The problem is to minimize $M-m$ subject to
\begin{align}
\delta^+(i)&=\sum_{\substack{j\in V:\\(i,j)\in E \lor (j,i)\in E}} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $i\in V$}\\
M &\ge \delta^+(i) &&\text{for $i\in V$}\\
m &\le \delta^+(i) &&\text{for $i\in V$}
\end{align}